# What does “10 years too soon” mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

I’ve read an article on the Verge. The title was

> YouTube bans robot fighting videos for animal cruelty roughly 10 years
>   too soon.

[And here’s the article.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwizkaDNuZXkAhVRA4gKHTjXA2gQzPwBegQIARAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.theverge.com%2Ftldr%2F2019%2F8%2F20%2F20825858%2Fyoutube-bans-fighting-robot-videos-animal-cruelty-roughly-10-years-too-soon-ai-google&psig=AOvVaw3qvVupyVJ_tWB9mBdsWYNn&ust=1566527975299338)

I can understand the first part of the title, which means “YouTube bans some videos for some reason”.

But I’m really confused about the later part

> 10 years too soon

Is it some sort of slang or idiom?

Besides, how does the word “roughly” function here?

Comment: “10 years too soon” suggests that You Tube is banning the video 10 years in advance.

Comment: @user067531 But why it’s 10 years, not 20 years or 5 years? And I haven’t seen any related information be mentioned in the article.

Answer (score 2):

Youtube banned the videos for animal cruelty, because it has robots fighting. The idea in the article is that robots will get conciousness and emotions in 10 years, thus it will be cruel; **however robots do not have emotions and cannot feel pain right now, this the ban is ten years too early.**